# Using MERGE with exact number of labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose you have a node like this one

```sql
MERGE (n1:Label1:Label2 { name:"name1" })
```

Now, I would like to be able to use the `MERGE` clause to create also the following new node:

```sql
MERGE (n2:Label1 { name:"name1" })
```

But since `n2` is a "sub-set" of `n1` *Neo4j* doesn't create a new node. So, my question is: is there a way to use `MERGE` to match/create a node with the exact number of specified labels and without using the `CREATE` clause?

Comment: If the property set is the same, then it won't create new nodes.

Comment: Got it! I was hoping there was something similar like in the match clause `MATCH (n:Label1 { name:"..."}) WHERE SIZE(LABELS(n)) = 1`, but for the merge

Comment: I am afraid `CREATE` is the only way here.

Comment: @jose_bacoy `MERGE (n1:Label1:Label2 { name:"name1" })` will not create 2 nodes, but rather one node with 2 labels

Comment: yes, it is. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `OPTIONAL MATCH` and `CREATE` to achieve the desired behavior:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2:Label1 {name: "name1"})
WHERE NOT (n2:Label2)
WITH n2
WHERE n2 IS NULL
CREATE (n3:Label1 {name: "name1"})
```